# Disable expansion for UWP Community Toolkit Expander

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using the [UWP Community Toolkit Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/expander) in my App. I'd like to be able to disable the expansion of the control (so it doesn't expand when clicked when certain criteria are met).

Ideally this would hide the expander arrow or make it grey as well as stopping the expansion from happening.

I could fork the [code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.0.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Layout/Expander) and make the necessary changes, but I was wondering if there are any simpler ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can retemplate the control in XAML (apply a style) and change the Visual States, without needing to change any logic

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake thanks for the suggestion-perhaps I'm misunderstanding Visual States, but I'm not clear how I would stop the expansion happening?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I oversimplified my question-I've been able to use your answer to achieve what I wanted but I had to rewrite some other code affected by using `IsEnabled`, sorry for the delay. Your answer addresses the question as presented above so I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally this would hide the expander arrow or make it grey as well as stopping the expansion from happening.

For your requirements, you just need edit the default `HeaderToggleButtonStyle` for  `Expander`.

Copy the default style from [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/7.0.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Layout/Expander/Expander.xaml#L12). add new animation into the `Disable` state to make the Arrow icon gray when `Expander` disable.

**This is edited style**

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="HoverPanel"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Fill="Transparent" />

                    <Slider
                        x:Name="ArrowRotation"
                        Maximum="180"
                        Minimum="-180"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Value="90" />

                    <FontIcon
                        x:Name="Arrow"
                        Margin="12"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        FontSize="12"
                        Glyph="&#xE76C;"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform />
                        </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                    </FontIcon>

                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,12,0"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="0.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="0.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="0.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="0.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <!--  gray arrow  -->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandDirectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightDirection" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="DownDirection" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftDirection">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ArrowRotation.Value" Value="-90" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="UpDirection">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ArrowRotation.Value" Value="-90" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
<controls:Expander HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderToggleButtonStyle}"
    x:Name="Expander2"
    Margin="0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    ExpandDirection="Down"
    Header="This is the header - expander 2"
    IsEnabled="False"
    IsExpanded="False">
    <Grid Height="256" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseHighBrush}">
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="This is the expanded content without a content overlay"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</controls:Expander>
```